# How use java to call python's qrcode?

Tags: java, python

Recently, I want to use java to call Python's QR code package, which I hope to use to generate QR code in the terminal interface. Like this and I want to use it in java.

> qr tomcat

```
█████████████████████████████
█████████████████████████████
████ ▄▄▄▄▄ █▀ ▄▀██ ▄▄▄▄▄ ████
████ █   █ ██▄▀ ██ █   █ ████
████ █▄▄▄█ █▄ ▀ ▄█ █▄▄▄█ ████
████▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█▄▀ █▄█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄████
████▄▀▄▀▄█▄█▀█▄▀▄▀█▀▄█▀ ▀████
██████▄▄ ▀▄█▀   ▀ ▄ ▀▄█ ▄████
████▄█▄▄█▄▄▄ █▄▄█▄  ██▀▄ ████
████ ▄▄▄▄▄ ██▄▀█▄█▀▀▄▄▄  ████
████ █   █ █▄█ ▀▄▀▄▄ ▀█ ▄████
████ █▄▄▄█ █▄▄  ▀ ▄▄▄▄█▀▄████
████▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█▄▄▄▄█▄▄█▄██▄▄████
█████████████████████████████
▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
```

but, want I run my java program, it occurred an ERROR. The ERROR message is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qrcode\image\pil.py", line 6, in
>
> from PIL import Image, ImageDraw   File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 69, in 
> from . import _imaging as core ImportError: DLL load failed: The speified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "D:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\qrcode\console_scripts.py", line 100,
> in 
> main()   File "D:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\qrcode\console_scripts.py", line 84,
> in main
> img = qr.make_image(image_factory=image_factory)   File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qrcode\main.py", line 289, in
> make_image
> from qrcode.image.pil import PilImage   File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qrcode\image\pil.py", line 8, in
>
> import Image   File "D:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 44, in 
> from . import ImageMode, TiffTags, UnidentifiedImageError, **version**, _plugins ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

And, this is my java program, I get Error Stream and print it in console.

```
package dragon;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class QR {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            Process process = runtime.exec("qr tomcat");
            InputStream input = process.getErrorStream();
            int len = 0;
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            while ((len = input.read(b)) != -1) {
                System.out.print(new String(b, 0, len, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            }
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So, I want to know how to make the java program to know the python's moudles?

Comment: Why do you want to use a Python library instead of a Java one in a Java program?

Comment: Because the python library can display on terminal such as CMD or POWERSHELL, and I don't know what java program can. And All I know is to produce QRCODE pictures. If you know some java program can do like this python's qrcode. Please tell me and I can use it replace the python's library.

Comment: Today, I find a java progarm that can do like the python's. But, I want to know how to resole that question? I think it's a interesting questtion.